# Does Pathfinder have a spell like Lesser Geas from 3.5?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, content-identification

I was wondering if there is an equivalent spell to [Lesser Geas](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/geasLesser.htm) in Pathfinder, since I have not been able to find it.

The purpose I need the spell for is binding. I just read a guide for binding that says:

> Cast lesser geas on her. Order her to retrieve a copper piece, which
>   you lay on the other side of your summoning room, and leave her there.
>   Each day she will suffer a -2 penalty to all your ability scores, up
>   to a -8 penalty for failing too retrieve the copper piece. Charisma
>   mod down to -3.

Is that possible in Pathfinder as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

Pathfinder has the [Geas, Lesser](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/geas-quest) spell. It should be in the Core Rulebook as a variant of the Geas/Quest spell.

As the wording is essentially identical to the 3.5 spell, it should work for the scenario described in your question.

Comment: perfect thanks a lot. I was looking for "Lesser Geas" on the wizard spells list on that page and could not find it. Now the binding can begin!